# When in the day should I train to optimize Recovery and to limit DOMS?

Tags: recovery, sleep, muscle-recovery, doms

Assuming that the exercise does not influence the quality and timing of sleep.

If I do not sleep much the day before, should I train later in the day.

Answer (score 1):

[Delayed Onset Muscle Soreness (DOMS)](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/19155/why-do-my-muscles-ache-the-day-after-i-lift-how-come-not-asap-after-my-workout/19157#19157) has nothing to do with time of day unless there is some research I'm unaware of.

[Sleep, however, is required for muscle growth and recovery from training](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5749041/), as expressed in the referenced study. You need (roughly, and this changes in certain populations) 7 hours of sleep to fully recover.

> ...sleep quality was positively associated with muscle strength, and
>   short sleep duration was associated with reduced muscle strength. Even
>   after adjusting for a number of potentially confounding variables,
>   these associations did not change.

So since sleep is required and DOMS has nothing to do with time of day, I'll stick with Ivo's answer that [the best time of day to exercise is the time that you'll regularly do it](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/44/7091).